# add and then read info from that file using rcptt

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcptt

I am using rcptt to automate my application. 
One test case is,

```
- add a file 
- then my app will read info from that file and proceed further if
 i click on next button.
```

To do this, i am using the below code

```
set-dialog-result File  [concat [get-workspace-location | str] "/proj/folder/sample-file.txt"]
get-editor "editor" | get-button Add | click
get-button "Save (M1+S)" | click
```

It can add the file but it can not read info from the file when i proceed further.

It shows error

```
could not be opened for reading
```

But the file is there as i checked that manually.

what is wrong i am doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong you are trying to add a new file, save it and then open the saved file?

You can use read-file command to read a file.

example:  read-file -uri "C:/Users/kaneezr/Desktop/WorkspaceRcptt/XATest/dataFile"

Here I am able to read a file by using the read-file option and providing a uri for it.

You can refer to the following as well:
https://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/blog/2015/08/12/file-and-clipboard-content.html

I am not sure if it will help but you can try and see.